# jsonPath filter expression with email address

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

In jsonPath I'm trying to filter objects with several values. One possable value is an email address. Since the @ is used as a pointer to the current object it is failing.

Example json string

```
{
"report": {
    "Author": [
        {
            "value": "John",
            "count": "58",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "key": "FileSize",
                    "value": "12314"

                },
                {
                    "key": "Date",
                    "value": "2000-01-01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "Jane",
            "count": "1",
            "fields": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "Foo@bar.com",
            "count": "58",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "key": "FileSize",
                    "value": "12314"

                },
                {
                    "key": "Date",
                    "value": "2000-01-01"
                },
                {
                    "key": "tags",
                    "value": "a,b,c,d"
                }         
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "Bill",
            "count": "2",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "key": "FileSize",
                    "value": "14"

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

If you use

```
$.report.Author[?(@.value==='John')]
```

the result is

```
"[{"value":"John","count":"58","fields":[{"key":"FileSize","value":"12314"},{"key":"Date","value":"2000-01-01"}]}]"
```

But since the email address has an @ sign jsonPath returns false on

```
$.report.Author[?(@.value==='Foo@bar.com')]
```

Anyone know of a way to escape the @ sign or a differnet method to evaulating the object?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$.report.Author[?(@.value==='Foo\\u0040bar.com')]
```

I tested it using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) with this [jsonpath library](https://npmjs.org/package/JSONPath).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefiantJS and write XPath on JSON structures. Try out the lib and test XPath on your JSON here:
http://defiantjs.com/#xpath-evaluator

I've pasted in your json data and tested this XPath and it works:

```
//Author[value="Foo@bar.com"]
```

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with a new method; "search" - which returns an array and in javascript, it looks like this:

```
var author = JSON.search(json_data, "//Author[value="Foo@bar.com"]");

console.log( author[0].value );
// Foo@bar.com

console.log( author[0].count );
// 58
```